# Optimizing SMO with RBFKernel (C and gamma) in Weka

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, classification, weka, svm

I'm trying to train a set of ~30,000 instances using an SMO classifier with an RBFKernel in Weka. I'm using grid search to find the optimal values for the parameters C and gamma. Here is my configuration:

```
weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch -E ACC -y-property classifier.kernel.gamma -y-min -10.0 -y-max 5.0 -y-step 1.0 -y-base 10.0 -y-expression pow(BASE,I) -filter weka.filters.AllFilter -x-property classifier.c -x-min 5.0 -x-max 20.0 -x-step 1.0 -x-base 10.0 -x-expression I -sample-size 100.0 -traversal COLUMN-WISE -num-slots 1 -S 1 -W weka.classifiers.functions.SMO -- -C 1.0 -L 0.0010 -P 1.0E-12 -N 0 -V -1 -W 1 -K "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RBFKernel -C 250007 -G 0.01"
```

I let it run for > 9 hours with no result, Weka's status message remains as "Building model on training data...". At first I thought grid search was the problem, but when I tried to train using the default values for C and gamma without performing a grid search I got the same result. I tried using a PolyKernel instead and the classifier was trained in a couple of seconds (but not in grid search).

How can I get the RBFKernel to work (using the default values and in grid search)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

- **Using logarithmic steps** `XExpression = pow(BASE,I)`, `XMin = -5`, `XMax = 5`, `XStep = 1` and `XBase = 10` (same for Y).
- **Using a filter** For my purposes I used a `DistributionBasedBalance` filter with `p` set to some value.
- **Increasing the number of execution slots** I set `numExecutionSlots` to 4 (the number of cores in my machine).

Comment: I can't find numExecutionslots or DistributionBasedBalance in Weka GUI, in the GridSearch options. Can you please tell me if I am looking at the right place. 

Also considering I have a CPU with 64 GB Ram, what are the Max and Min Values X and Y one can have?

Answer (score 1):

Do you preprocess your training data? It is very important for the RBF kernel. You could try to normalize the features to [-1,1] and try the RBF kernel again.

Comment: Yes, I normalize the feature to [0,1]. I can get grid search to produce results if I use a very small random sample (100 instances or so). Other than that, no luck.

Comment: If there are many training instances, it may take much time (In September, an experiment took me 20 days to do grid search and didn't produce reasonable results. The size of the training dataset is ~30000,too.)to complete the grid search because it does cross validation in it. Try to select parameters(C and gamma) on small subset of the training data using grid search and use the parameters to train model with the whole training dataset. It may help.